# How to ask Samba to follow symlinks for user & password less guest account

Tags: samba

I want to configure Linux Samba 4.0.9 for providing read-only access to directory content (symlinks to files from other locations) in user & password less way. Basically any LAN user should have access to content without any user/pass questions. I have following smb.conf:

```
[global]
    load printers = no
    guest account = guest
    name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n .
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
    preserve case = yes
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    encrypt passwords = true
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    dns proxy = no
    printing = bsd
    server string = Home Server
    invalid users =
    unix password sync = false
    workgroup = Home-Server
    log level = 2
    syslog only = yes
    os level = 20
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = yes
    syslog = 2
    security = user
    map to guest = Bad User
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    short preserve case = yes
    max log size = 1000
    unix extensions = no
    interfaces = lo lan0
    bind interfaces only = yes
    follow symlinks = yes
    wide symlinks = yes

[tv]
    comment = Myth Television
    available = yes
    browsable = yes
    public = yes
    writeable = no
    path = /myth/tv/pretty

[root]
    comment = Root FS
    path = /
    valid users = root
    force user = root
    force group = root
    admin users = root
    writeable = Yes
```

Above config gives me user/pass less access to [tv] - but attempt to access symlink gives me "Permission denied". Exactly the same symlink is working OK for [root] so I think issue is related to user/pass less access mode (where user/pass is bad and Samba is using 'map to guest = Bad User' directive). May somebody hint me about proper config?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

In order to allow symbolic links, you need to use `wide links` directive, instead of `wide symlinks`. I think that `wide symlinks` may be a typo, because I can't find a reference to it in the `man` page.

```
wide links = yes
```

Sources:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1439092
- http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

**Edit**: The version of SAMBA that my server is running is 3.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Well - it looks like I have old option name in smb.conf: instead of "wide symlinks = yes" there should be "wide links = yes". Now it works.